# What is the notation of equal or almost equal?

Tags: notation

I have a measure X and the value of $X$ is equal to or almost $1000$. This can be $X=1000$, $X=999$, or $X=998$.

Is it correct if I use the symbol $≃$ such that $X ≃ 1000$?

Comment: I like $X=999\pm 1$ more.

Comment: $\approx$ is a better symbol.  But what exactly do you mean it can but $x=1000, 999, 998$.  Can it only be those three values? Does it have to be an integer? Can it be more than $1000$. Can it be less than $998$.  Is it $999$ with a margin of error of $1$?

Comment: where you wrote "notion" in the title, did you mean "notation"?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen that, but we have $\approx$ available in MathJax from \approx.  I think it is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly used is definitely the double tilde symbol:

$\approx$ [`$\approx$`](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Relation_operators)

≈ [(U+2248)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2248/index.htm)

But there are quite a few alternative symbols: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Approximately_equal

Comment: I have seen \$\doteq\$ ($\doteq$), which is listed there